# NavBar back button behavior

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I have an app with a navigation controller. When the app is launched, a table view is loaded, clicking on a row, opens up a webview loading a page (let's call that page1). Page1 might contain links, the user clicks on a link and new page is loaded (page2). The user then wants to go back to page1 and clicks the back button in the nav bar. Clicking the back button takes him to the table view and not page1.

How can i change that behavior or intercept the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebView has a property **'goBack' & 'goForward'**
I would recommend that you create a separate buttons for browsing back & forth. 
Implement following actions for these buttons.

- (void)actionBackButtonPressed {

  [myWebView goBack];

}

-(void)actionForwardButtonAction
{

```
[myWebView goForward];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage the UIWebView navigation yourself using the delegate methods and custom UI as the others have mentioned. To answer your question re: the Back button on the navigation item, you cannot override the default back button behavior but you can put your own button in the navigationItem (typically in `viewDidLoad`) with:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWith...
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myBackButton;
[myBackButton release];
```

You can choose which `init...` method of `UIBarButtonItem` best suits your app. You can use this button in conjunction with your web view if you like but IMHO it would be strange to mix the navigation paradigm of a UIWebView with the navigation paradigm of UINavigationController. However, it's your app so just trying to add to your toolbox.

Also note that there is no way to create a UIBarButtonItem that looks like the standard back button. If you want the tapered, "back arrow" style you'll have to supply your own button images.

Answer (score 0):

We have `UIWebViewDelegate` method that keep track of content loading in webView. So, when user tap on any link on page1. You should use `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` method . In this method just create another new `viewController`(same as of page1) and push newController with `loadRequest`.

Thanks,